# Remove item from json object on checkbox uncheck in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angularjs v1.4.7. I have fetched result set from db and constructed data as jsonobject.

```
$scope.originalEmpList= 
{
    "depts": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "IT",
            "software_team": "Ram, Rahim",
            "hr_team": "",
            "fin_team": ""
            
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": HR,
            "software_team": "",
            "hr_team": "Mohan",
            "fin_team": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": PM,
            "software_team": "Ram",
            "hr_team": "Mohan",
            "fin_team": "John"
        }
    ],
    "softwarelist": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "employee_name": "Ram",
            "employee_role": "Software",
            "dept_id": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "employee_name": "Rahim",
            "engineer_role": "Software",
            "dept_id": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "employee_name": "Ram",
            "engineer_role": "Software",
            "dept_id": "3"
        }
        
    ],
    "hrlist": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "employee_name": "Mohan",
            "employee_role": "HR",
            "dept_id": "2"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "employee_name": "Mohan",
            "employee_role": "HR",
            "dept_id": "3"
        }
        
    ],
    "finlist": [
        {
            "id": 6,
            "employee_name": "John",
            "employee_role": "Account",
            "dept_id": "3"
        }
        
    ]
}
```

and showing below table on UI side from above jsonobject

```
    Select All Checkbox  Dept  Softwares   HRs    Fins
    
    Checkbox1             IT    Ram, Rahim 
    Checkbox2             HR                Mohan 
    Checkbox3             PM    Ram         Mohan  John
```

Based on above checbox selection respective team members will be shown.

For Eg: If Checkbox1 is selected then only show names for that dept.

```
Softwares : Ram, Rahim
```

Similarly if we select checkbox1 and checkbox2 then show names for checked depts.

```
Softwares : Ram, Rahim
Hrs: Mohan
```

And if we select all 3 checkboxes then show names.

```
Softwares : Ram, Rahim, Ram
Hrs: Mohan, Mohan
Fins: John
```

I have kept unchanged the original emp list and copied it to employeeList

```
$scope.employeeList = $scope.originalEmpList;
```

Update object based on checkbox selection.

```
$scope.UpdateOnCheckUncheck = function () {
    $scope.employeeList = $scope.originalEmpList;
    $scope.filteredArtist = [];
    
    // Collect unchecked depts  
    $scope.unchecked_depts = filterFilter($scope.employeeList.depts, 
       function (dept) {
        return !dept.Selected;
    });

    $scope.filteredSoftware= [];

    // Passing unchecked depts to remove from employeelist 
    angular.forEach($scope.unchecked_depts, function(dept) {
        $scope.updateCheckedDept(dept);
    });
};


$scope.updateCheckedDept = function(dept) {
    **// Approach 1 using reduce to copy into new array and then assign back to employeeList**
    Object.keys($scope.employeeList.softwarelist).reduce((object, 
      key) => {
       if (dept.id !=$scope.employeeList.softwarelist[key].dept_id) 
      {
       $scope.filteredArtist.push($scope.prismlist.artistlist[key]);
      }
     //return object
    }, {})

    $scope.employeeList.softwarelist= $scope.filteredSoftware;
    **//Approach 2 using splice
    angular.forEach($scope.employeeList.softwarelist, 
    function(soft, index){
    if(dept.id === soft.dept_id){
     $scope.employeeList.softwarelist.splice(index);
    } 
    });
    **//Approach 3 using slice**
};
```

**//Approach 4 - Thinking to call DB and construct query and filter at server side but calling db on every checkbox change will be costly.**

Actually after updating back to `$scope.employeeList` , it works fine for the first time uncheck but when uncheck another checkbox i assign `$scope.employeeList = $scope.originalEmpList;` but this doesn't get the initial data fetched from db rather than it updated to first time uncheck object value.

On Every check/uncheck how to update employeelist to populate the output as shown above. Also suggest me the best approach to use in terms of performance. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.employeeList = $scope.originalEmpList;
```

is like referencing to $scope.originalEmpList. Any updates to $scope.employeeList is the same as updating $scope.originalEmpList.

Instead, you try angular.copy() which creates a deep copy of the array.

```
$scope.employeeList = angular.copy($scope.originalEmpList);
```

Comment: Sure, I will check with that, Can you please suggest me over removing unchecked row data from Object, which one to use reduce/splice/slice?

Comment: hmmmm, i cant tell u about the performance for each approach. But judging from above, my personal opinion would be to use splice as there is no need to declare one more variable to hold the resulted array. Maybe someone with more experience can give us a bit more of insight to this.